# Search data in dbf-visual foxpro 9

Tags: visual-foxpro

I want to display records in a grid form a dbf table that constantly changes every time I enter a letter in a textbox. Can anyone address my concern? Im using Visual foxpro 9 and this is my first time with foxpro9. thank u...

Answer (score 0):

I think you're saying that as you type, you want the list of records in the grid to be filtered based on what you've typed. I haven't tried it, but this looks like it'll give you what you want:

http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=1214

Alternatively, this page offers a grid class that includes incremental search and a number of other features: http://www.sweetpotatosoftware.com/spsblog/2008/11/25/VisualFoxProGridEnhancements.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your problem as i understand it, that you have a grid on a form that displays data from table 
also you have a testbox that is linked to a field in the same table that the grid is displaying data from, so in order to prevent the data from changing when inserting data in the textbox simply change the link in the textbox or cancel it, also make the grid if you are using it for only displaying data to read only from the properties.